# Flutter Sliver List with Future Json Data

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I am running into an issue trying to populate a `SliverFixedExtentList` with children from a JSON API response. I have a function `_getMyListOfCustomJsonObjects()` that returns a `Future<'List<'CustomJsonObject>>`. I am fairly new to flutter, but my understanding of `SliverLists` is that they should behave similarly to a `ListView`. I have been able to populate a `ListView` of these children using a `FutureBuilder` and `ListView.builder`. However, making the change to a `SliverList` is throwing me an error.

Below is an example of my code

```
CustomScrollView(
   slivers: [
SliverAppBar(),
FutureBuilder(
  future: _getMyListOfCustomJsonObjects,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data != null)
      return SliverFixedExtentList(
        itemExtent: 150,
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return
           Container(
           color: Colors.red, 
           child: Text('${snapshot.data[index].Name}'));
        }, 
         childCount: snapshot.data.length),
      );
    else {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:50),
        //alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: <Widget>[
            new CircularProgressIndicator(
              value: null,
              strokeWidth: 4,
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFFe5ac3b),
              semanticsLabel: "Loading",
              valueColor:
                  new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Color(0xFF12336c)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  },
),
],
),
```

I think I might be close, but this is my first time trying to use Slivers so I'm not sure if I'm missing a key component to make this all work. Below are the errors I get when I try to run this code.

```
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true. 

flutter: Another exception was thrown: Duplicate GlobalKeys detected in widget tree.
```

Any suggestions to achieve populating a `SliverList` with `Future<List<CustomJSONObject>>`?

Comment: Can you provide the whole stack trace? it seems that there is an exception before the ones you mentioned, since they both say "Another exception was thrown".

Comment: Alright- after doing more digging into the stack trace I found out that it was the contents of the Else {} that was giving me the errors I was receiving. To fix this, I used SliverFillRemaining() inside of the Else{}- However, it seems the Async Snapshot is returning null. Would this have anything to do with when the widget is being built?